# Every "apt upgrade" or similar -> The following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I ran this command by error:

> sudo dpkg **--auto-deconfigure** -i libc6_2.29-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb

and now  I have this problem:

```
a16jorgetc@lnxd-i4e01:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
         Breaks: nscd (< 2.29)
         Breaks: nscd:i386 (< 2.29)
         Recommends: libidn2-0 (>= 2.0.5~) but 2.0.4-1.1build2 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 nscd : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

```
a16jorgetc@lnxd-i4e01:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libc-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
         Breaks: nscd (< 2.29)
         Breaks: nscd:i386 (< 2.29)
         Recommends: libidn2-0 (>= 2.0.5~) but 2.0.4-1.1build2 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
 nscd : Depends: libc6 (< 2.28) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

```
a16jorgetc@lnxd-i4e01:~$ apt-cache policy libc-bin libc6
libc-bin:
  Installed: 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.27-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://reposteis.ateis.local/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libc6:
  Installed: 2.29-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.29-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2.29-0ubuntu2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.27-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://reposteis.ateis.local/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS x86_64

Anyone can help me solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What release/OS are you running?  I've seen package versions for disco & bionic, so I'd check your sources.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I updated the question with the result for the command, I don't really know what  --auto-deconfigure does, so as I mentioned, I've done this by error and I don't know how to revert to back state

Comment: I updated in the post with the correct command, to be honest I'm not understanding the problem... I think installing this package (with the first command of the post) I broke the other packages, and now I have to restore the initial state of the other packages. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I missed the `-i` (or install) option in your `dpkg` command; it's installed a disco package and yes is a problem!   It's a disco package, which means your system isn't LTS any longer as contains 19.04 package(s) which EOL in a few months. It's also a core package.  I'm unwilling to advise, but if I was in your position, I'd just `dpkg -r libc6_2.29-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb` to remove it; then hope `sudo apt -f install` would re-install the correct bionic package (otherwise I'd `wget` it and manually install). I believe the `dpkg -r` of package followed by `apt -f install` will fix your problem.

Comment: `dpkg -r libc6_2.29-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb` It says `dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64` So I don't know how to uninstall this package to install the right one, because most of other packages depend on libc6

Comment: Why I didn't want to advise..  Your options are --force-things  (not wise; you're not equipped for that), or probably safer `dpkg -i` the correct package (though it may need to be forced too; but at least it's what you want & need to do!).  Read the messages before you press enter (though there is always your backups). If you `dpkg -i` you'll likely want to `apt-mark` to restore your packages to as they should be... though you've likely already messed up that database given you got yourself in this mess (ie. I'm guessing it's not your first time).  Setup a VM in this position & practice there

Comment: Thanks! I've solved the problem by reinstalling the correct package. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by reinstalling the correct package from the correct version:

```
wget http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo apt upgrade
```

Thanks to 'guiverc'

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks